# XeLaTeX and font selection

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

This is almost a duplicate of  but its answer doesn't work for me.

I downloaded the complete Roboto superfamily ([Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto), [Roboto Condensed](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Condensed), [Roboto Slab](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Slab) and [Roboto Mono](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Mono)) and I want to use all the families, all the weights, widths, variants and styles inside my document. Of course mine is not a real need, but I want to understand clearly how the `fontspec`package works.

All my .ttf files are located in a directory called `fonts`, subdivided into directories with the name of the family (`fonts/Roboto`, `fonts/Roboto_Condensed`, etc...).

Inpired by [XeLaTeX and font weight](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404237/xelatex-and-font-weight), the [package documentation of `fontspec`](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/xetex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) and the [texdoc font installation guide](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/Type1fonts/fontinstallationguide.pdf) I included the Roboto font in this way.

```
\setmainfont{Roboto}[
  Path = fonts/Roboto/,
  Extension = .ttf,
  %-- Upright --%
  FontFace={ul}{n}{Font=*-Thin},
  FontFace={l}{n}{Font=*-Light},
  FontFace={m}{n}{Font=*-Regular},
  FontFace={mb}{n}{Font=*-Medium},
  FontFace={b}{n}{Font=*-Bold},
  FontFace={eb}{n}{Font=*-Black},
  % %-- Italic --%
  FontFace={ul}{it}{Font=*-ThinItalic},
  FontFace={l}{it}{Font=*-LightItalic},
  FontFace={m}{it}{Font=*-Italic},
  FontFace={mb}{it}{Font=*-MediumItalic},
  FontFace={b}{it}{Font=*-BoldItalic},
  FontFace={eb}{it}{Font=*-BlackItalic},
]
```

But I obtain the following error:

> !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>
> !
>
> ! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
>
> !
>
> ! The font "Roboto" cannot be found.
>
> !
>
> ! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
>
> !
>
> ! For immediate help type H .
>
> !...............................................

But the path is right. In fact with this MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Roboto}[
  Path = fonts/Roboto/,
  Extension = .ttf,
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  %-- Upright --%
  FontFace={ul}{n}{Font=*-Thin},
  FontFace={l}{n}{Font=*-Light},
  FontFace={m}{n}{Font=*-Regular},
  FontFace={mb}{n}{Font=*-Medium},
  FontFace={b}{n}{Font=*-Bold},
  FontFace={eb}{n}{Font=*-Black},
  % %-- Italic --%
  FontFace={ul}{it}{Font=*-ThinItalic},
  FontFace={l}{it}{Font=*-LightItalic},
  FontFace={m}{it}{Font=*-Italic},
  FontFace={mb}{it}{Font=*-MediumItalic},
  FontFace={b}{it}{Font=*-BoldItalic},
  FontFace={eb}{it}{Font=*-BlackItalic},
]

\DeclareRobustCommand{\ulseries}{\fontseries{ul}\selectfont}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lseries}{\fontseries{l}\selectfont}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mseries}{\fontseries{m}\selectfont}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mbseries}{\fontseries{mb}\selectfont}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ebseries}{\fontseries{eb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textul}{\ulseries}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textl}{\lseries}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textm}{\mseries}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textmb}{\mbseries}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textb}{\bseries}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texteb}{\ebseries}

\begin{document}

\sffamily
\textul{Abc Thin} {\ulseries Thin}

\textl{Abc Light} {\lseries Light}

\textm{Abc Light} {\mseries Light}

Abc Regular

\textmb{Abc SemiBold} {\mbseries SemiBold}

\textb{Abc Bold} {\bseries Bold}

\texteb{Abc ExtraBold} {\ebseries ExtraBold}

\end{document}
```

I obtain this warning

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmss/ul/n' undefined (Font)
>
>   using`TU/lmss/m/n' instead on input line 53.
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmss/l/n' undefined (Font)
>
>   using`TU/lmss/m/n' instead on input line 55.
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmss/mb/n' undefined (Font)
>
>   using`TU/lmss/m/n' instead on input line 61.
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/lmss/eb/n' undefined (Font)
>
>   using`TU/lmss/m/n' instead on input line 65.

And this result, that clearly is not what I want.

[image: example]

Comment: Maybe `Path=./fonts/Roboto`? Where is the `fonts` directory located?

Comment: In the same directory where my document is. In the first case it throws the error but if I add `UprightFont = *-Regular` as shown in the MWE it doesn't throw errors but only warning.

Comment: So I think that the error is in `FontFace={..}{...}{Font=*-...}`. I checked the last brackets and all the files have the correct name. For the first two brackets I used the values in Tables A.1 and A.3 of [font installation guide](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/Type1fonts/fontinstallationguide.pdf) as suggested by the fontspec documentation.

Comment: You should use `\setsansfont` if you want Roboto for sans serif

Comment: What an idiot I am.

Comment: However a doubt still remains. Why it give me the error when I remove the `UprightFont = *-Regular`? I still have `FontFace={m}{n}{Font=*-Regular}` so shouldn't be a problem, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't select the roman font family but the sans serif one as pointed out by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) in the comments. However an alone of mistery still remains in my opinion: why xelatex throw an error if I don't put `UprightFont = ...`?

However, this is the final result

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{RobotoSlab}[
  Path = fonts/Roboto_Slab/,
  Extension = .ttf,
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  %-- Upright --%
  FontFace={ul}{n}{Font=*-Thin},
  FontFace={l}{n}{Font=*-Light},
  FontFace={m}{n}{Font=*-Regular},
  FontFace={b}{n}{Font=*-Bold},
]

\setmonofont{RobotoMono}[
  Path = fonts/Roboto_Mono/,
  Extension = .ttf,
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  %-- Upright --%
  FontFace={ul}{n}{Font=*-Thin},
  FontFace={l}{n}{Font=*-Light},
  FontFace={m}{n}{Font=*-Regular},
  FontFace={mb}{n}{Font=*-Medium},
  FontFace={b}{n}{Font=*-Bold},
  % %-- Italic --%
  FontFace={l}{it}{Font=*-LightItalic},
  FontFace={m}{it}{Font=*-Italic},
  FontFace={mb}{it}{Font=*-MediumItalic},
  FontFace={b}{it}{Font=*-BoldItalic},
]

\setsansfont{Roboto}[
  Path = fonts/Roboto/,
  Extension = .ttf,
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  %-- Upright --%
  FontFace={ul}{n}{Font=*-Thin},
  FontFace={l}{n}{Font=*-Light},
  FontFace={m}{n}{Font=*-Regular},
  FontFace={mb}{n}{Font=*-Medium},
  FontFace={b}{n}{Font=*-Bold},
  FontFace={eb}{n}{Font=*-Black},
  % %-- Italic --%
  FontFace={ul}{it}{Font=*-ThinItalic},
  FontFace={l}{it}{Font=*-LightItalic},
  FontFace={m}{it}{Font=*-Italic},
  FontFace={mb}{it}{Font=*-MediumItalic},
  FontFace={b}{it}{Font=*-BoldItalic},
  FontFace={eb}{it}{Font=*-BlackItalic},
]

\DeclareRobustCommand{\ulseries}{\fontseries{ul}\selectfont}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lseries}{\fontseries{l}\selectfont}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mseries}{\fontseries{m}\selectfont}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mbseries}{\fontseries{mb}\selectfont}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bseries}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ebseries}{\fontseries{eb}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textul}{\ulseries}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textl}{\lseries}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textm}{\mseries}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textmb}{\mbseries}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textb}{\bseries}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texteb}{\ebseries}

\begin{document}

\textul{Abc Thin} {\ulseries Thin} \par
\textl{Abc Light} {\lseries Light} \par
\textm{Abc Regular} {\mseries Regular} \par
\textb{Abc Bold} {\bseries Bold} \par
\ttfamily
\textul{Abc Thin} {\ulseries Thin} \par
\textl{Abc Light} {\lseries Light} \par
\textm{Abc Regular} {\mseries Regular} \par
\textmb{Abc Medium} {\mbseries Medium} \par
\textb{Abc Bold} {\bseries Bold} \par
\itshape
\textl{Abc Light} {\lseries Light} \par
\textm{Abc Regular} {\mseries Regular} \par
\textmb{Abc Medium} {\mbseries Medium} \par
\textb{Abc Bold} {\bseries Bold} \par
\sffamily\upshape
\textul{Abc Thin} {\ulseries Thin} \par
\textl{Abc Light} {\lseries Light} \par
\textm{Abc Regular} {\mseries Regular} \par
\textmb{Abc SemiBold} {\mbseries SemiBold} \par
\textb{Abc Bold} {\bseries Bold} \par
\texteb{Abc Black} {\ebseries Black} \par
\itshape
\textul{Abc Thin} {\ulseries Thin} \par
\textl{Abc Light} {\lseries Light} \par
\textm{Abc Regular} {\mseries Regular} \par
\textmb{Abc SemiBold} {\mbseries SemiBold} \par
\textb{Abc Bold} {\bseries Bold} \par
\texteb{Abc Black} {\ebseries Black} \par

\end{document}
```

and this is the result.

[image: result]

Hope that it can be helpful to someone in the future.

If egreg want to put his comment as answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: If you don’t include UprightFont=... it tries to load RobotoSlab.ttf, which doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 2):

Nice self-answer!  I do have one thing to add: the official names for font weights in LaTeX are:

- Ultra Light: `ul`
- Extra Light: `el`
- Light: `l`
- Semi Light: `sl`
- Medium/regular/book `m`
- Semi bold: `sb`
- Bold: `b`
- Extra Bold: `eb`
- Ultra Bold: `ub`

These combine with an optional width class to form a series.  The official width classes are:

- Ultra Condensed (50%) `uc`
- Extra Condensed (65.5%) `ec`
- Condensed (75%) `c`
- Semi Condensed (87.5%) `sc`
- Medium (100%) `m`
- Semi Expanded (112.5%) `sx`
- Expanded (125%) `x`
- Extra Expanded (150%) `ex`
- Ultra Expanded (200%) `ux`

A weight class followed by a width class form a font series.  (Medium width is normally omitted.)  So, `{bx}{it}` is bold expanded italic, and `{sbc}{sl}` is semi-bold condensed slanted/oblique.

Although you can use any arbitrary letter-strings as series and shape names and `fontspec` won’t complain, if you’re intending to use commands like `\textl` on more than just this one font, you’re probably better off using the standard names.  You’ll also ease migration from a few NFSS packages, such as `nfssext-cfr`.

Following these conventions, semibold should be `sb` rather than `mb`, and thin could be either `ul` or `el`.

Since tracking the information down is a pain, the `fontspec` manual endorses this scheme without describing it and gives a footnote to the  “LaTeX Font Selection” documentation from LaTeX2e.  That document says, “Whenever possible,  you  should  use  the  series  and  shape  names  suggested  in *The LaTeX Companion* since this will make it easier to combine new fonts with existing fonts.”  This is the book by Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens, published by Addison_Wesley. The information is on page 414 of the second edition.

#### PS

Thanks for the link to the “Font Installation” document that also lists the series `{mb}` between `{m}` and `{sb}` and `{db}` between `{sb}` and `{b}`.  I see that a few packages, such as `nfssext-cfr`, support them.  It’s a good idea to use these series for a font family that comes in separate Regular/Book, Medium, Semibold and Bold weights, or Semibold, Demibold and Bold.  If, in fact, you want to use all those different weights within the same document, which many people think you shouldn’t.

If there’s only one font weight between Regular and Bold, though, my personal recommendation is to call it `{sb}`, even if the official name is Medium or Demibold.  That is what Computer Modern Demi does. Or you could even define `{mb}`, `{sb}` and `{db}` for every font family, even if `{sb}` is the same as `{mb}` and `{db}` is the same as `{b}`, so that you can use `\fontseries{mb}` freely and always get something sensible. Of course, if you don’t care about compatibility with other packages or being able to replace the font family with another in your preamble, you can call it whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, are you sure about **official** names for weights? Could you link a reference? I would appreciate very much. I found that `m` stands for _book_ and _regular_ while `mb` stands for _medium_ according to NFSS series (ref. [http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/fonts/Type1fonts/fontinstallationguide.pdf#appendix.A](Font Installation Guide - Appendix A)). I choose _medium_ instead of _semibold_ because the font name was already with _medium_. Anyway, I'm too noob to say what is the difference between a medium font and a semibold one.

Comment: Also, I agree that tracking the information down is a pain. There are a lot of references but not a clear rule. I still didn't understand if these are conventions or real rules.

Comment: @gvgramazio The reference is page 414 of *The LaTeX Companion* (cited in the LaTeX2e documentation and the *fontspec* manual). (As I wrote.)

Comment: @gvgramazio Thanks for the reference. On page 90, it does list medium-bold and demi-bold as additional weights. This is presumably because some fonts come in demibold or medium weights in addition to semibold. (Usually, Medium is lighter than Semibold and Demibold is heavier.)  I see that some packages, including `nfssext-cfr`, do use those font weights. If there’s only one font weight between Regular and Bold, however, I’d recommend calling it `{sb}`, as for example Computer Modern Demi does.

Comment: @Davislor — I'm wondering in fontspec whether I could just allow the user to say `BoldFont=x,BoldFont=y,BoldFont=z`, and this would produce three weights with series `b1`, `b2`, `b3`, ... , then provide user commands like `\textbolder` and `\textlighter` to move between them. Do you think this would be a good approach as a user?

Comment: I'm flattered you'd ask my opinion! Since it's another topic, I think I'll answer in chat when I'm more awake.