# On the Extra and Ultra Bold Font Series

Tags: fonts, bold

I could never be able to use Extra and Ulta Bold font series.
Do you know how to define these.
Below is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
%\usefont{enc}{family}{series}{shape}
\newcommand{\bfont}{\usefont{T1}{cmr}{b}{n}\fontsize{10}{\baselineskip} \selectfont}
\newcommand{\ubfont}{\usefont{T1}{cmr}{ub}{n}\fontsize{10}{\baselineskip} \selectfont}
\newcommand{\ebfont}{\usefont{T1}{cmr}{eb}{n}\fontsize{10}{\baselineskip} \selectfont}
\begin{document}
Normal\\
{\bfont Bold}\\
{\ubfont Ultra Bold}\\
{\ebfont Extra Bold}\\

\end{document}
```

Which creates:
[image]

Comment: Are you using a bespoke version of the Computer Modern font family, i.e., one which defines the "ultra bold" and "extra bold" font weights? I've been using TeX and LaTeX for roughly 30 years, and I've *never* heard of these two font weights having been created for Computer Modern. The only CM font weights I know about are normal (aka medium), bold extended, and bold.

Comment: Hi Mico. I used just the regular Computer Modern. The font weights can be found on page 26 of:   https://texdoc.org/serve/latex2e.pdf/0

Comment: @Aria that just lists how the weights are named, it does not say that every font has designs in all those weights (most do not) computer modern (and latin modern) just have bold and bold extended b and bx

Comment: Do you know which fonts have those weights?

Comment: @Aria Some example fonts with both Ultra bold and extra bold would be the "Inter" and "Noto" font families.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Do you see the quality degradation in my picture above for bold?

Comment: @Aria In the screenshot, all the lines appear to have rather bad quality.

Comment: yes your fonts look pixilated, are you using miktex and have not installed the cm-super package (type 1 computer modern fonts) ?

Comment: There is much good information in @davislor answers about fonts, e.g.: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432917/xelatex-and-font-selection/444664#444664 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598328/inter-font-black-style-for-a-few-words-but-rest-in-normal-weighted-bold/598370#598370. Usually there will be 10 to 30 or more font files for a font with many weights and widths, and you can tell from the filename what it has (things like ultrabold condensed, extra light expanded, italic bold display, and so on - many combinations). Some fonts have a  lot, other fonts only 1 or 2.