# Change Boldness of Certain Fonts

Tags: fonts, fontspec, bold, mactex

For some certain fonts, they have different level of "boldness". For example, `Avenir Next` has `Ultra Light` `Light`, `Regular`, `Medium`, `Demi-Bold`, `Bold` and `Condensed Bold`... Below is an example done by Pages.

[image]

How do I use / define those "boldness" in LaTeX? To make it simple, please give me a minimal work sample where multiple boldness of `Avenir Next` is used.

Comment: If the font provides different *weights* then you can simply use them with fontspec as `\setmainfont{Avenir Next Light}`. If that does not work for you please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

After some attempts, I think a possible solution is
`\newfontfamily\<what_ever_command>{Avenir Next <Regular/Bold>}[Ligatures=TeX]`.
Such as

```
\newfontfamily\avr{Avenir Next Regular}[Ligatures=TeX]
\newfontfamily\avm{Avenir Next Medium}[Ligatures=TeX]
\newfontfamily\avd{Avenir Next Demi Bold}[Ligatures=TeX]
\newfontfamily\avdi{Avenir Next Demi Bold Italic}[Ligatures=TeX]
```

And then I can use those commands.

```
\avd This is "Avenir Next Demi Bold" font.
```

or

```
\avdi This is "Avenir Next Demi Bold Italic" font.
```

or

```
\avr Why are they different?
```

If someone has better solution, please kindly tell me.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/264275 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404395 for a better approach.